# How to parse received json data in action

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, struts2-json-plugin

I am sending json array data from JSP to Action class for that I have included `struts2-json-plugin`.
I want to parse it to receive it as a `ArrayList` elements.
 my code is

**In JSP:**

```js
$.ajax({
        url: "UpdateNotification",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {ids: JSON.stringify(ids)},
        success: function(data) {
            alert("success " + data.st);
        }
    })
```

**In action:**

```java
public class Test extends ActionSupport {
    ArrayList<String> ids = new ArrayList<String>();

        public ArrayList<String> getIds() {
            return ids;
        }

        public void setIds(ArrayList<String> ids) {
            this.ids = ids;
        }

        public String updateNotification() {
                 System.out.println("ID ARE " + getIds());
                    for (String a : getIds()) {
                        System.out.println("data " + a);
                    }
             }
      }
```

On running it is showing  data

```
ID ARE [["25","27","28"]]
  data ["25","27","28"]
```

How can I get one data as one array element in action.

EDIT I am trying to get data as

```
ids(0)=25;
ids(1)=27;
ids(2)=28;
```

Comment: Which version of S2? Older versions of S2 json plugin don't support direct json arrays. Have you configured jsoninterceptor?

Comment: I am using struts2.3.15.3

Comment: NO I have not configured anything only included `struts2-json-plugin`

Comment: Do you really need json? Have you tried ajax with traditional like I told you in your previous question?

Comment: I resolved that problem by adding appropriate  `struts2-json-plugin` here I am sending array from ajax and yes I want to read it as json.

Comment: How you resolved it if you still can't do what you want? You don't need json to send array via ajax. Using json is just one of the ways to do it.

Comment: O k  now how can I access it in action

Comment: By following my comment in your previous question.

Comment: Don't use raw ajax with `ajax()` call, use `post()` and `get()`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get javascript array in Action](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31805980/how-to-get-javascript-array-in-action)

Comment: @RomanC  Using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31805980/how-to-get-javascript-array-in-action I find the way how to access data in Action But in this question I want to parse received data as arrayList element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Json `stringify` method returns an array of values in json format something like `["25","27","28"]`. But to convert to a list you need to remove `[` or `]` characters to submit CSV values. Because only CSV values could be converted to a list.  Try

```
data: {ids: JSON.stringify(ids).replace(/[\[\]]/g,'')},
```

Comment: It is not replacing [ and ] getting the same value

Comment: @xrcwrn Listen, I give you an idea and you try it yourself, I can't test it in my environment, but I know that replacement should work, and if it doesn't then you should test it. You can also let me know what's wrong with it and I will update the answer.

Comment: No, It's not ok, I need my answers to be upvoted and accepted. If you don't want to help me why should I help you?

Comment: I tried `data: {ids: JSON.stringify(ids).replace(/[\[\]-]/g, "")},` Which is removing  `[]` but still in server it is showing `ID ARE ["25","27","28"]
data "25","27","28"`

Comment: It's correct, the `ArrayList` uses `toString()` to print this. What else do you need? And it's suspicious escaping, using regex in java you need to escape `\\` character.

Comment: then how it will show ids(0)=25;
ids(1)=27;
ids(2)=28;

Comment: Whare do you want to show it, in console? `System.out.println("ids("+i+")="+ids.get(i)+";");`

Comment: No I wat receceive it in ArrayList as id(0) value=25 ans similar

Comment: I want received data should be populated in arrayList ids like ids(0)=25; ids(1)=27; ids(2)=28;

Comment: I didn't get, isn't it printed to the console?

Comment: at server side ` System.out.println("data " + a);` printing data "25","27","28"

Comment: This is because elements of the list is of type string, try `List<Integer>`.

Comment: Not Working it is giving value as string

Comment: I don't understand what are you saying.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85407/discussion-between-xrcwrn-and-roman-c).