# Submit JS function value on submit in Struts 2

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts2, struts-tags

How to pass values that set inside hidden field in `<s:form>` by JavaScript `function` to action class on click of `<s:submit>` button of this `<s:form>`?

Comment: Just put a setter for each parameter (hidden or not) in the action.

Comment: By having an action property for it, just like a non-hidden field. The type of the property depends on what you are sending back, if it's not a collection it obviously shouldn't be in CSV format.

Answer (score 0):

The values should be in the CSV format like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31851177/573032) answer.

That will also give you an idea about type of property which you should *bind* to the hidden field. For example you can use `List<Integer>` or `Integer[]` for the property that set the values `25, 27, 28`.

Struts2 has a built-in converter that converts such values to the list or array automatically.

Also note the instance variable in the action class can't be used by OGNL (by default) if it is not accessible by security manager or has not `public` accessors like getters and setters. In Struts2 submitted values are populated to the instance variable by the [`params` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/parameters-interceptor.html) which is indeed invokes OGNL to do the job.